# Find average stream velocity over a cross-section of a cylinder, given $v(r) = k(R^2 − r^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, average

I'm doing integration homework and a question that I am not sure how to approach popped up.

> The velocity (in centimeters per second) of blood r cm from the
>   central axis of an artery is given by  $v(r) = k(R^2 − r^2)$,  where k
>   is a constant and R is the radius of the artery. Suppose that $k = 1200$
>   and $R = 0.3$. Find the average velocity  v  of the blood across a cross
>   section of the artery.[image]

Since I don't really know how to approach this problem and the question was on the section for integration I'll post what I did, but I know it isn't right. I'm just posting to show that I don't just want you all to do my homework.

So $v(r) = k(R^2 − r^2)$ so I plugged in the given $k$ and $R$. and I ended doing $1200\int .03^2-r^2dr$ and got $.0108-400r^3$ and solved for $r$ and hoped for the best, but it was futile. A step by step solution of this would be greatly appreciated. I know the answer is 72, I just do not know how to get to that answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to find the average value of this function.  In general, if you have an integrable function $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then the average value of that function is given by $\displaystyle \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) dx$.  If you've been assigned this problem, you *should* be able to find this formula discussed somewhere in your textbook.  (Maybe try the index?).  Otherwise, you can find a quick proof of this formula by [clicking here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ProofIntProp.aspx#Extras_IntPf_AvgVal).

In our case, we have a function of $r$, and $r$ can vary anywhere from $0$ to $0.3$ (the velocity of the blood is changing depending only on the value of $r$).  Therefore, setting up our integral, we have:

$$\text{Average Velocity} = \frac{1}{0.3}\int_0^{0.3}1200(0.3^2 - r^2)dr$$

And I'll leave that calculation for you.  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!